# SIGSEGV inside ntdll.dll while creating a window

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I'm trying to create a simple GUI app that shows a single window on Windows 7 x64. I'm using FFI in order to call the Windows API from rust, but I keep getting SIGSEGV inside ntdll.dll. Am I doing something wrong?

The whole code can be found at https://github.com/rillomas/rust_sample, but I'll post the main stuff here.

- winapi.h and winapi.c are C wrappers for Windows API. They get compiled to a static library (libwinapi)
- winapi.rs is a crate that links to libwinapi for FFI.
- main.rs links to winapi and displays a window.

The info of `rustc -v` is the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin\rustc.exe 0.11-pre-nightly (7d725a3 2014-04-21 23:01:39 -0700)
host: i686-pc-mingw32
```

## winapi.h

```
#ifndef WINAPI_H_
#define WINAPI_H_
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define API_CALL_CONVENTION __stdcall

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    HWND handle;
} WindowContext;

bool API_CALL_CONVENTION createWindow(WindowContext* context, LPCTSTR title);
void API_CALL_CONVENTION mainLoop(WindowContext* context);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // WINAPI_H_
```

## winapi.c

```
#include "winapi.h"

bool API_CALL_CONVENTION createWindow(WindowContext* context, LPCTSTR title) {
    WNDCLASS wnd;
    memset(&wnd, 0, sizeof(wnd));
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wnd.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)DefWindowProc;
    wnd.style         = CS_OWNDC;
    wnd.hInstance     = hInstance; 
    wnd.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wnd.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wnd.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH); 
    wnd.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wnd.lpszClassName = TEXT("opengles2.0");

    if (!RegisterClass (&wnd) ) {
        return false; 
    }

    DWORD wStyle = WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX;

    // Adjust the window rectangle so that the client area has
    // the correct number of pixels
    RECT windowRect;
    windowRect.left = 0;
    windowRect.top = 0;
    windowRect.right = context->width;
    windowRect.bottom = context->height;

    BOOL result = AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect, wStyle, FALSE);
    if (!result) {
        return false;
    }

    HWND handle = CreateWindow(
                        TEXT("opengles2.0"),
                        title,
                        wStyle,
                        0,
                        0,
                        windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
                        windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL);

    // Set the ESContext* to the GWL_USERDATA so that it is available to the 
    // ESWindowProc
    SetWindowLongPtr(handle, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG) (LONG_PTR) NULL);

    if(handle == NULL) {
      return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(handle, TRUE);
    context->handle = handle;
    return true;
}

void API_CALL_CONVENTION mainLoop(WindowContext* context) {
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    int done = 0;
    // DWORD lastTime = GetTickCount();

    while (!done) {
        int gotMsg = (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) != 0);
        // DWORD curTime = GetTickCount();
        // float deltaTime = (float)( curTime - lastTime ) / 1000.0f;
        // lastTime = curTime;

        if ( gotMsg ) {
            if (msg.message==WM_QUIT) {
                done=1; 
            } else {
                TranslateMessage(&msg); 
                DispatchMessage(&msg); 
            }
        } else {
            SendMessage( context->handle, WM_PAINT, 0, 0 );
        }

        // Call update function if registered
        // if (esContext->updateFunc != NULL ) {
        //     esContext->updateFunc ( esContext, deltaTime );
        // }
    }
}
```

## winapi.rs

```
#![crate_id = "winapi#0.1"]
#![crate_type = "lib"]
extern crate libc;
use libc::types::common::c95::{c_void};
use libc::types::os::arch::c95::{c_int};
use std::ptr::null;

// win32 related types
type LPCWSTR = *u16;
pub type HMODULE = *c_void;

pub struct WindowContext {
    pub width: c_int,
    pub height: c_int,
    pub handle: *c_void
}

#[cfg(windows)]
#[link(name="winapi")]
#[link(name="gdi32")]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn createWindow(context: *WindowContext, title: LPCWSTR) -> bool;
    fn mainLoop(context: *WindowContext);
}

// #[cfg(target_os = "win32", target_arch = "x86")]
#[cfg(windows)]
#[link(name="kernel32")]
extern "system" {
    fn GetModuleHandleW(lpModuleName: LPCWSTR) -> HMODULE;
}

pub fn get_module_handle(name: Option<~str>) -> HMODULE {
    match name {
        Some(n) => std::os::win32::as_utf16_p(n, |buf| unsafe { GetModuleHandleW(buf) }),
        None => unsafe { GetModuleHandleW(null())}
    }
}

pub fn create_window(context: *WindowContext, title: ~str) -> bool {
    std::os::win32::as_utf16_p(title, |buf| unsafe { createWindow(context, buf) })
}

pub fn main_loop(context: *WindowContext) {
    unsafe { mainLoop(context) }
}
```

## main.rs

```
extern crate winapi;
use std::ptr::null;

fn main() {
    let handle = winapi::get_module_handle(None);
    println!("handle: {}", handle);
    let context = winapi::WindowContext {
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        handle: null()
    };
    let result = winapi::create_window(&context, ~"Sample Window");
    if !result {
        println!("Failed to create window");
        return;
    }

    winapi::main_loop(&context);
}
```

## build log

```
PS C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-win32-dwarf-rev5/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-win32-dwarf-rev5/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- w
orks
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-win32-dwarf-rev5/mingw32/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-builds/x32-4.8.1-win32-dwarf-rev5/mingw32/bin/g++.exe --
 works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/masato/Documents/GitHub/rust_sample

PS C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample> mingw32-make.exe
Scanning dependencies of target winapi
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/winapi.dir/winapi/winapi.c.obj
Linking C static library libwinapi.a
[ 50%] Built target winapi
Scanning dependencies of target winapi_sample
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/winapi_sample.dir/winapi_sample.c.obj
C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample\winapi_sample.c: In function 'main':
C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample\winapi_sample.c:6:5: warning: format '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigne
d int', but argument 2 has type 'HMODULE' [-Wformat=]
     printf("Module addres: 0x%x\n", addr);
     ^
Linking C executable winapi_sample.exe
[100%] Built target winapi_sample

PS C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample> rustc winapi.rs

PS C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample> rustc .\main.rs -L .
```

## gdb output log

```
PS C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample> gdb .\main.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-w64-mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample\main.exe...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample\main.exe
[New Thread 7060.0x1a0c]
[New Thread 7060.0x422c]
handle: 0x400000

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76f3fc62 in ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76f3fc62 in ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x76f3fc62 in ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x762ceba2 in MapViewOfFile () from C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll
#3  0x70a25313 in UxTheme!GetThemeBitmap () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#4  0x70a251e5 in UxTheme!GetThemeBitmap () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#5  0x70a253e5 in UxTheme!GetThemeBitmap () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#6  0x70a25a77 in UxTheme!GetThemeBitmap () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#7  0x70a25cc4 in UxTheme!GetThemeBitmap () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#8  0x70a22094 in UxTheme!CloseThemeData () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#9  0x70a24260 in UxTheme!IsThemePartDefined () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#10 0x70a2421d in UxTheme!IsThemePartDefined () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#11 0x70a246ed in UxTheme!ThemeInitApiHook () from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
#12 0x74daacd4 in UnregisterClassW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
#13 0x74daab0e in UnregisterClassW () from C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
#14 0x76f3010a in ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher () from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#15 0x0028fa9c in ?? ()
#16 0x74dbc6f1 in USER32!AdjustWindowRect () from C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
#17 0x004cc196 in createWindow@8 (context=0x28fcc8, title=0x9f3618 L"Sample Window")
    at C:\Users\masato\Documents\GitHub\rust_sample\winapi\winapi.c:85
#18 0x00403bfd in create_window::closure.1804 ()
#19 0x00403b8a in os::win32::as_utf16_p::h611005080090069878::v0.1 ()
#20 0x00403a2e in create_window::h0d38b3844b04f5aaEba::v0.1 ()
#21 0x0040174c in main::h8f0d1dbc5859ab98gaa::v0.0 ()
#22 0x0042cac8 in start::closure.7798 ()
#23 0x004c035c in rt::task::Task::run::closure.40266 ()
#24 0x004c46b5 in rt::unwind::Unwinder::try::try_fn::hf6246262045efccdJS9::v0.11.pre ()
#25 0x004cc006 in rust_try ()
#26 0x004c0234 in rt::task::Task::run::h08ef5174e2ea21abwj8::v0.11.pre ()
#27 0x0042c97d in start::h07163dfeb7ec96475Ld::v0.11.pre ()
#28 0x0042c829 in lang_start::h59c5ddaef2ad2b17pLd::v0.11.pre ()
#29 0x00401810 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see the following problems with your code:

- You call `SetWindowLongPtr` before checking whether or not `CreateWindow` succeeded.
- You should pass `windowRect.left` and `windowRect.top` to `CreateWindow` for the `x` and `y` coordinates.
- Your message loop is somewhat odd. What's wrong with the classic `GetMessage` loop?
- The code that sends `WM_PAINT` messages is wrong. You cannot do that. If you want to repaint, use `InvalidateRect`.

I doubt that any of the above will explain your error. However, I'd certainly want to sort out the message loop. It should look like this:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

If I take your Win32 C code and compile it with my C compiler, then it runs just fine. Which leads me to think that the issue is with the linking process that you are using. An access violation in `AdjustWindowRect` seems pretty odd. The stack trace has a bunch of functions from the theme API. How is your program manifested?

Comment: I didn't have any ideas about manifests. Since the error is related to the visual style, I'll experiment with manifests and see what I can do (maybe refer to this [link](http://www.geekthis.net/blog/62/visual-styles-in-win32-api-c-gcc-mingw)).